# add a button with jQuery for an existing jQuery button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

Can someone please help me/explain how can I do this or if it's possible? 
I have a simple html code for a grocery list :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Let's buy...</title>         
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h2 class="title">My grocery list<span id="counter"></span> </h2>
        <ul id="list-items"></ul>
        <div id="newItemButton"><button href="#" id="showForm">new item</button></div>
        <form id="newItemForm">
            <input type="text" id="itemDescription" placeholder="Add item..."/>
            <input type="submit" id="addButton" value="add" />    
        </form>   
        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I am the user is adding elements to the list - when the user adds an item, that item comes with a button. Now, I want that button "change item" to add 4 more buttons with append(), and I want each button, when clicked to change the color of the item eg red, green, orange and grey - depending on user preference. 
I am trying to add those buttons but I don't seem to add it, it does not appear on the page - just to say - I tried to add only one button :) .
Here is my jQuery code ... :

```js
$(function() {
    let $list, $newItemForm, $newItemButton;
    let item = '';
    $list = $('ul');
    $newItemForm = $('#newItemForm');
    $newItemButton = $('#newItemButton');

    function updateCount() {
        let items = $('li').length;
        $('#counter').text(items);
    }
    updateCount();

    $newItemButton.show();
    $newItemForm.hide();
    $('#showForm').on('click', function() {
        $newItemButton.hide();
        $newItemForm.show();
    });

    $newItemForm.on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let text = $('input:text').val();
        $list.append('<li>' + text + '<button id="btn-change">change item</button><hr></li>');
        $('input:text').val('');
        updateCount();    
    });
```

and this is the = 'button adding process' :

```js
   $('#btn-change').one('click', function() {
            let b = $('<input/>').attr({
                type: "button",
                id: "hot",
                value: 'hot'
            });
            $("button").append(b);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other things that need to be addressed such as multiple buttons, how you instantiate the event handler and more.  However to just answer your "why does my new input not appear".

A button element should not contain and input element.  You can see why that would not make sense.  Thus to create a new input of type button after that and not append TO that so, use the `.after`.  Now assume that the actual clicked on is the one we want to append to we can use `this` and append to our button with id `btn-change`

```
$('#btn-change').one('click', function() {
   let b = $('<input/>').attr({
        type: "button",
        id: "hot",
        value: 'hot'
    });
    $(this).after(b);
});
```

Here is another option simply using a different method that performs the same function, does the same thing but perhaps the name makes the intent more clear.

```
$('#btn-change').one('click', function() {
   let b = $('<input/>').attr({
        type: "button",
        id: "hot",
        value: 'hot'
    });
    b.insertAfter(this);
});
```

Now we can add a button, we observe that we added this button we are clicking dynamically, thus we need to allow our event handler to be dynamic as well, that is attach it to a container for the button.

`list-items` is our container, so we attach to that.

```
$('#list-items').one('click', '#btn-change',function() {
   let b = $('<input/>').attr({
        type: "button",
        id: "hot",
        value: 'hot'
    });
    b.insertAfter(this);
});
```

Now that we have our event handler we also note that the duplicate id is not valid so we modify to use a class instead of an id.

```
$('#list-items').one('click', '.btn-change',function() {
   let b = $('<input/>').attr({
        type: "button",
        class: "hot",
        value: 'hot'
    });
    b.insertAfter(this);
});
```

Now that we have some explanation out of the way, lets do a solution

```js
$(function() {
  let $list, $newItemForm, $newItemButton;
  let item = '';
  $list = $('#list-items'); // use faster id
  $newItemForm = $('#newItemForm');
  $newItemButton = $('#newItemButton');

  function updateCount() {
    let items = $list.find('li').length; // get inside our list
    $('#counter').text(items);
  }
  updateCount();

  $newItemButton.show();
  $newItemForm.hide();
  $newItemButton.on('click', function() {
    $newItemButton.hide();
    $newItemForm.show();
  });

  function addButton(place, b) {
    let bt = $('<input/>').attr({
      type: "button",
      class: b + "button colorbutton",
      value: b
    }).data("colorclass", b + "thing");
    bt.insertAfter(place);
  }
  // perhaps change to button type not submit type?
  $newItemForm.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let text = $('#itemDescription').val(); // use fast id
    text = text=""?"new":text;//avoid empty text
    $list.append('<li><span class="desc">' + text + '</span><button type="button" class="btn-change">change item</button><hr></li>');
    $('#itemDescription').val('');
    updateCount();
  });
  $('#list-items').on('click', '.colorbutton', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.desc')
     .removeClass("hotthing greenthing orangething greything")
     .addClass($(this).data("colorclass"));
  });
  //Note the change here from discussion, still adds the buttons but more modular, disables button to avoid second click vs the .one, works for new items
  $('#list-items').on('click', '.btn-change', function() {
    $(this).prop("disabled", true); // only add once so disable it
    // add the color buttons, matches classes in css
    addButton(this, "hot");
    addButton(this, "green");
    addButton(this, "orange");
    addButton(this, "grey");
  });
});
```

```css
.hotbutton {
  color: red;
}

.greenbutton {
  color: green;
}

.orangebutton {
  color: orange;
}

.greybutton {
  color: grey;
}

.hotthing {
  background-color: red;
}

.greenthing {
  background-color: green;
}

.orangething {
  background-color: orange;
}

.greything {
  background-color: grey;
}

#list-items {
  border: solid lime 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h2 class="title">My grocery list<span id="counter"></span> </h2>
  <ul id="list-items"></ul>
  <div id="newItemButton"><button type="button" id="showForm">new item</button></div>
  <form id="newItemForm">
    <input type="text" id="itemDescription" placeholder="Add item..." />
    <input type="submit" id="addButton" value="add" />
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are dealing with is that you try to fire an event from a dynamic generated element. The **#btn-change** element was not loaded in the page when you attached the event. Based on the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/one/) you can add a selector. You will have to attach the event into a stable element of your page e.g **ul#list-items**

so your code would look like this

```
$("ul#list-items").one('click','#btn-change', function() {
        let b = $('<input/>').attr({
            type: "button",
            id: "hot",
            value: 'hot'
        });
        $("button").append(b);
});
```

Or you could attach the event grammatically.

Also i would like to suggest you to use classes instead of id for elements that would exist multiple times on the same page (e.g the `<button id='btn-change'></button>`) the id must be unique in your page.

So the code that i would suggest would look like this

```
$newItemForm.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let text = $('input:text').val();
    $list.append('<li>' + text + '<button class="btn-change">change item</button><hr></li>');
        $('input:text').val('');
        updateCount();    
});
```

changed the `id='btn-change'` to `class='btn-change'`

and the code of the btn-change click event

```
$('ul#list-items').one('click','.btn-change', function() {
    let btnContainer = $("<div></div>").css("display","inline-block").attr({
        class: "btn-container"
    });

    btnContainer.append(
        $('<input/>').attr({
            type: "button",
            class: "hot", //use class instead of id in case you generate more than 1 element
            value: 'hot'
        })
    ).append(
        $('<input/>').attr({
            type: "button",
            class: "green", //use class instead of id in case you generate more than 1 element
            value: 'green'
        })
    ).append(
        $('<input/>').attr({
            type: "button",
            class: "grey", //use class instead of id in case you generate more than 1 elements 
            value: 'grey'
        })
    ).append(
        $('<input/>').attr({
            type: "button",
            class: "orange", //use class instead of id in case you generate more than 1 element
            value: 'orange'
        })
    );

    btnContainer.insertBefore(this);
    $(this).hide();//or remove based on what you want to achieve

});
```

here I am using the **.btn-change** as selector and I am creating a container element to hold the four buttons then i add the container of four buttons before the **.btn-change** button and hide the button.

You can add later the part of code that will remove/hide the container of the four buttons and show the .btn-change button